# Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser on session null

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phpunit, selenium-grid

```
09:39:51.984 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser on session null
09:39:52.002 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://website.localhost] on session null
09:39:52.002 INFO - creating new remote session
09:39:52.003 INFO - Allocated session 4b3951d894ed4a2c94b7fd9758cd5554 for http://website.localhost, launching...
jar:file:/usr/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
09:39:52.071 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
09:40:12.129 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:346)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxLauncher.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:400)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:809)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:435)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:405)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:151)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
09:40:12.131 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser on session null
09:40:12.143 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://website.localhost] on session null
```

what i am doing ?

Step 1: Start the hub

The Hub is the central point that will receive all the test request and distribute them the the right nodes.

Open a command prompt and navigate to the directory where you copied the selenium-server-standalone file. Type the following command:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub`

Step 2: Start the nodes

Regardless on whether you want to run a grid with new WebDriver functionality, or a grid with Selenium 1 RC functionality, or both at the same time, you use the same selenium-server-standalone jar file to start the nodes.

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:44444/grid/register` (here 44444 is for the environment i am working)

Comment: now i am getting this error :

exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:44444/selenium-server/driver/': Timed out after 30000ms' in phar:///usr/bin/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/Driver.php:1066

please help !!

phpunit version 4.4.5

Comment: Have you validated that the server is running? Open the browser and go to the hub. See what browser the hub supports. make sure firefox is one of them. Could we see your code on how you are building the remote driver?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to compatibility issues between selenium and firefox.

You need to upgrade to the latest selenium server, [`2.44`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! As alec[xe suggested this is due to the compatibility issues between firefox and selenium. For firefox version higher than 30 you must use selenium 2.44 version.[Here's](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) the changelog of the selenium please take a look and decide which version of the selenium will fulfill your requirement.

[Click here to download the latest(2.44) version of the selenium.](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar)